# Run a function inside of a string

Tags: php, function

How to run a function inside of a string like the shown below in php:

```
echo "This page is under construction
      <br/><br/>Current Date: date('l jS \of F Y')";
```

I've used double-quoted string statement but the function didn't run at all and this is what I got on my screen after running the script:

> This page is under construction
>
> Current Date: date('l jS \of F Y')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not support functions being embedded in string values. The manual has a great page on string and [parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). You can embed variables however or concatenate strings with the function output.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I didn't know I can embed functions inside of the string but I knew the concatenate option. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't want to leave out an available solution even if it was already answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date:" . date('l jS \of F Y');
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

And the obligatory you-can-do-it-after-all answer:

```
$date = "date";
echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date: {$date('l jS \of F Y')}";
```

But of course the string concatenation is the advisable option here.

Comment: I was looking for his solution as well. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me whether this technique has a name or buzz word or something? How can I find more about that?

Comment: It's on the page Paul linked. They call it "complex curly variable syntax", but it's also known as "variable expressions".

Comment: @Braveyard, bear in mind that this technique is very rarely used in PHP. You mostly find this type of interpolation in languages like ruby.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error message complaining that the variable $date is an undefined function (because $date is undefined). And when I remove the $, the construct is treated as a string. This is with PHP 7.2. It looks like nobody tested this answer, or I made a mistake.

Comment: My use case isn't a quoted string like `"abc"`. It's a block-quoted (heredoc) string `<<<"_w3_"
abc
_w3_;
`. In other words, it would be nice to force a function call inside such a block quote, for greater simplicity of syntax.

Comment: The documentation says that `{}` work only for certain kinds of variables, not for function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need just to concatenate the date return to your string:

```
echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date: " . date('l jS \of F Y')";
```

In PHP the . is used for string concatenation.

Comment: Duplicate answer; doesn't answer the actual question.